# Fatal error: Class not found in AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have generated a new Bundle (ImgBundle) following the Symfony documentation, but when reloading the app in the browser it does not recognize the main class of the bundle.

Here is my ImgBundle.php:

```
<?php

namespace ImgBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class ImgBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

AppKernel.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new ImgBundle\ImgBundle(),
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

        if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
        }
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

}

Here is the error:

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you need to change your composer.json I think with psr-4 autoload like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    }
```

After you need to launch inside your console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Have the same issue with Symfony 3, my composer.json looks like the answer but cannot find SonataAdminBundle

Answer (score 1):

With Symfony 2.8, I had to delete app/cache folder manually