# Symfony generated Bundle doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, bundles

I just created a new project with symfony 3.4 and i generated a bundle, the message from the bundle generation said it's all good, then i just start to work just by running clear cache command it display this error message

> php.exe C:\wamp64\www\bunead\bin\console cache:clear
>   Fatal error: Class 'AnnuaireBundle\AnnuaireBundle' not found in C:\wamp64\www\bunead\app\AppKernel.php on line 19

here's my Appkernel.php

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new AnnuaireBundle\AnnuaireBundle(),
        ];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class not found in AppKernel.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990181/fatal-error-class-not-found-in-appkernel-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add It inside your composer

Try to change your composer.json to this for example:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    }
```

After inside your console launch this:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: @MarwenJamel Then you didn't do it right.  There have been over a dozen identical questions over the last week or so.  Ales and I are having a competition to see how many points we can get answering the same question over and over.

Comment: We suppose this solved my problem,Is there a permanent solution for this problem ? Because  im working on big project and I need many bundles..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the autoload of symfony.

Open you composer.json file and edit :

AnnuaireBundle\AnnuaireBundle

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "AnnuaireBundle\\": "src/AnnuaireBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

then, run the next command in your composer:

composer dumpautoload