# Symfony Bundle references "@Bundle" - FileLocatorFileNotFoundException

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I am currently building my own Symfony bundle (I am using version 3.3). It works fine so far, but now I wanted to move the bundle-specific service definition out of my `app/config/services.yml` to a service definition within the bundle.

I created a `src/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` and followed the guide [How to Load Service Configuration inside a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html) to load it. That works just fine, but I thought that the paths inside the newly created `services.yml` look a bit ugly:

```
MyBundle\:
    resource: '../../*'
    exclude: '../../{Tests}'
```

So I thought it would look a little cleaner, if I use the `@Bundle`-notation instead:

```
MyBundle\:
    resource: '@MyBundle/*'
    exclude: '@MyBundle/{Tests}'
```

However, than I was facing the error:

> **FileLocatorFileNotFoundException**
>
> The file "@MyBundle" does not exist (in: `<...>\MyBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config`), where `<...>` corresponds to an absolute path.

I also tested whether it was a naming issue of the bundle name, but when I have a wrongly named bundle reference in the `app/config/services.yml`, e.g. `@SomeBundleThatDoesNotExist` then I get a different error:

> **FileLoaderLoadException**
>
> Bundle "SomeBundleThatDoesNotExist" does not exist or it is not enabled.

So my question is: Why does the `@Bundle`-notation work fine in the `app/config/services.yml` but not in the `src/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the service remember make public for external use:

autowire: true

public: true

But, if your symfony dont know where is the bundle please chec this answer:

[Symfony generated Bundle doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017856/symfony-generated-bundle-doesnt-work/45021550#45021550)

Comment: The autoloading does work. It really seems to be the `@`-annotation that does not work.

I have also looked into Symfony's code in the meantime and I assume that the problem is, that I am loading the bundle's `services.yml` using the `Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator` class, that does not check for `@`-references. However, the `app/services.yml` seems to be loaded with the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator` class, that looks for resources references with a leading `@` and acts accordingly.

Comment: Thus, I assume that '@'-references are not meant to work inside bundle configs.